# What attacks hit all opponents in a Pokemon horde encounter?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I want to know so that I can sort out a Pokemon with one of those moves.

Comment: what do you mean by "hoarde"?

Comment: Sorry. I meant horde.

Comment: why has my question been voted down? There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: If you have another question, ask a new question. Don't edit new questions into current question, as that invalidates the answers.

Comment: Is that why it was voted down? If so; if I tried to ask another one with those goalposts it would have been classified as a duplicate.

Comment: I don't know why it was voted down, there's no way of telling. Arqade users generally don't like questions asking for a list of something, but the downvotes could be for whatever reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many moves that target multiple enemies. A list, categorised by the rules in which they effect multiple targets, can be found [here](http://pokemondb.net/move/group/multi-target). You will find more information on each individual move, as well.

## Targets Adjacent

Boomburst, Bulldoze, Discharge, Earthquake, Explosion, Lave Plume, Magnitude, Parabolic Charge, Petal Blizzard, Searing Shot, Self-Destruct, Sludge Wave, Surf, Synchronoise, Teeter Dance.

## Targets Adjacent Foes

Acid, Air Cutter, Blizzard, Bubble, Captivate, Dark Void, Dazzling Gleam, Diamond Storm, Electroweb, Eruption, Glaciate, Growl, Heat Wave, Hyper Voice, Icy Wind, Incinerate, Leer, Muddy Water, Origin Pulse, Poison Gas, Powder Snow, Precipice Blades, Razor Leaf, Razor Wind, Relic Song, Rock Slide, Snarl, String Shot, Struggle Bug, Sweet Scent, Swift, Tail Whip, Twister, Water Spout.

## Targets All

Gravity, Hail, Haze, Magic Room, Mud Sport, Perish Song, Rain Dance, Sandstorm, Sunny Day, Trick Room, Water Sport, Wonder Room .

## Targets All Foes

Heal Block, Imprison, Spikes, Stealth Rock, Sticky Web, Toxic Spikes.

## Targets All Allies

Aromatherapy, Heal Bell, Light Screen, Lucky Chant, Mist, Quick Guard, Reflect, Safeguard, Tailwind, Wide Guard.

Comment: Could you put a list here please? My computer doesn't accept very many links. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Thank you. This is the most useful answer I've gotten. So thank you.

Comment: One last thing, I've noticed the source I used covers all of Pokemon. So some moves may not be available in X/Y. If you are able to get on the website directly, each move is linked to its own database file, and lists its in-game description. If there is an in game description for XY, the move is available in XY. 

It's my pleasure to help, but for future reference, general comments saying thanks are generally discouraged ;).

Comment: @Timelord64 All moves should be available in XY. If I recall, no moves have ever been removed from Pokemon between generations, just altered.

Answer (score 3):

Moves that hit everyone in a horde battle are:

- Teeter Dance
- Boomburst
- Petal Blizzard
- Discharge
- Searing Shot
- Earthquake
- Lava Plume
- Bulldoze
- Selfdestruct
- Sludge Wave
- Surf
- Explosion

Note that all weather attacks will also hit every enemy. Also, spikes will affect every enemy pokemon.